# What's the RGB values for Ubuntu's default terminal (Unity)?

Tags: colors, default, virtual-console

I'm running Windows Subsystem for Linux and the color in Windows console is bad. I like the color palette in Ubuntu 16.04 very much. I've already known how to change the colors in a Windows console, and all I need is the colors from Ubuntu terminal. I use 16.04 with its default desktop environment, ubuntu-unity. What's the colors' RGB values in the default terminal? Foreground colors and background colors.

```
echo -e "\e[30;1mA\e[31;1mB\e[32;1mC\e[33;1mD\e[34;1mE\e[35;1mF\e[36;1mG\e[37;1mH"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19728-01/820-2550/term_em_colormaps.html), these are the default RGB values for terminals that support 16 colors:

```
Color_0     Black           0   0   0
Color_1     Light red       255 0   0
Color_2     Light green     0   255 0
Color_3     Yellow          255 255 0
Color_4     Light blue      0   0   255
Color_5     Light magenta   255 0   255
Color_6     Light cyan      0   255 255
Color_7     High white      255 255 255
Color_8     Grey            128 128 128
Color_9     Red             128 0   0
Color_10    Green           0   128 0
Color_11    Brown           128 128 0
Color_12    Blue            0   0   128
Color_13    Magenta         128 0   128
Color_14    Cyan            0   128 128
Color_15    White           192 192 192
```

But the Ubuntu color map is slightly different:

```
Color_0     Black           0   0   0
Color_1     Light red       187 0   0
Color_2     Light green     0   187 0
Color_3     Yellow          187 187 0
Color_4     Light blue      0   0   187 
Color_5     Light magenta   187 0   187 
Color_6     Light cyan      0   187 187 
Color_7     High white      187 187 187 
Color_8     Grey            85  85  85
Color_9     Red             255 85  85
Color_10    Green           85  255 85
Color_11    Brown           255 255 85
Color_12    Blue            85  85  255 
Color_13    Magenta         255 85  255 
Color_14    Cyan            85  255 255 
Color_15    White           255 255 255
```

You can change these default colors by putting something like this in your `~/.bashrc` file (with *P0* to *PF* being the colors, and the rest of it is RGB in hex):

```
#change default colors
echo -en "\e]P0000000" #black
echo -en "\e]P1FF0000" #lightred
echo -en "\e]P200FF00" #lightgreen
echo -en "\e]P3FFFF00" #yellow
echo -en "\e]P40000FF" #lightblue
echo -en "\e]P5FF00FF" #lightmagenta
echo -en "\e]P600FFFF" #lightcyan
echo -en "\e]P7FFFFFF" #highwhite
echo -en "\e]P8808080" #grey
echo -en "\e]P9800000" #red
echo -en "\e]PA008000" #green
echo -en "\e]PB808000" #brown
echo -en "\e]PC000080" #blue
echo -en "\e]PD800080" #magenta
echo -en "\e]PE008080" #cyan
echo -en "\e]PFC0C0C0" #white
```

Answer (score 15):

1. Open the Ubuntu default terminal, right-click it's title bar and select **Always On Top** to keep it easily accessible for a screenshot.  Then open GIMP.  You can install GIMP by typing this into a terminal:  **sudo apt install gimp**
2. In GIMP, go to **File->Create->Screenshot**
3. Select **Take a screenshot of a single window** and **include window decoration**
4. Set the **Delay** to 2-5 seconds
5. Click the **Snap** button.
6. After the Delay time, your mouse pointer will become a Plus-Sign/Cross.  Click the Terminal window with this cross.
7. A screenshot of the window will then open up in GIMP.
8. You can then use the **color picker tool** to click on any color in the screenshot, which sets the foreground color.  You will see thee foreground color box change color as you click different colors.  You can then click on the foreground color rectangle and it will open a window with your RGB values for that color.
9. If you are having a hard time picking the color of the fonts, you can zoom in and out in GIMP the + and - keys, or you can do the usual CRTL+mouse-wheel up/down.

The terminal background color is:  R=48, G=10, B=36

The terminal white font is:  R=255, G=255, B=255

Comment: That's hex #300a24 for the terminal background.